# not able to convert this code from vb6 to vb.net - SET string = New Application

Tags: vb.net, parameters, vb6, vb6-migration

I have some vb6 code that I'm trying to use in my Vb.net application but am having an extremely difficult time

this is code from VB6....

```
Dim CurrentVersion as cApplication

Set currentVerion = New Application
```

and I have a function called - getLatestInformation in a different class with a few paremeters looks like this....

```
GetLatestVersion(VaID As Integer, VaMode As Integer, ValueID As Integer)
```

IN my vb6 application i called it like this...

```
currentVersion.getLatestVersion 3,4,5
```

I am unable to do anything but DIM currentVersion as CApplication. Having some hard time with this.

Comment: What is the specific issue that you are having?  Are you getting an error?  Please post any clues that could help us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Set" is no longer an object assignment keyword.  Instead you can do

```
Dim currentVersion As cApplication = New Application()
```

or

```
Dim currentVersion As cApplication
currentVersion = New Application()
```

assuming cApplication is a compatible type with Application. Both ways create an "Application" object and assign it to the currentVersion variable.

You would then call using

```
currentVersion.getLatestVersion(3, 4, 5)
```

VB.NET has changed a lot of syntax in this way--you may want to get a text to help you along with all the changes.

Comment: Something needs a more depth investigation here: What relationship exists between a _cApplication_ class and an _Application_ one?

Comment: Application must be a type of cApplication.  That is, either Application inherits from cApplication (which would need to be a class) or Application implements cApplication (which would need to be an interface).  
If Application is actually the .NET class System.Windows.Application, then the presumably user-defined cApplication will never be either.